# Concatenate Sparse Vectors in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Say you have two Sparse Vectors.  As an example:

```
val vec1 = Vectors.sparse(2, List(0), List(1)) // [1, 0]
val vec2 = Vectors.sparse(2, List(1), List(1)) // [0, 1]
```

I want to concatenate these two vectors so that the result is equivalent to:

```
val vec3 = Vectors.sparse(4, List(0, 2), List(1, 1)) // [1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Does Spark have any such convenience method to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a slight problem understanding `SparseVectors`. Therefore I will make a little explanation about them, the first argument is the number of features | columns | dimensions of the data, besides every entry of the `List` in the second argument represent the position of the feature, and the values in the the third `List` represent the value for that column, therefore `SparseVectors` are locality sensitive, and from my point of view your approach is incorrect.

If you pay more attention you are summing or combining two vectors that have the same dimensions, hence the real result would be different, the first argument tells us that the vector has only 2 dimensions, so `[1,0] + [0,1] => [1,1]` and the correct representation would be `Vectors.sparse(2, [0,1], [1,1])`, not four dimensions.

In the other hand if each vector has two different dimensions and you are trying to combine them and represent them in a higher dimensional space, let's say four then your operation *might* be valid, however this functionality isn't provided by the [SparseVector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector) class, and you would have to program a function to do that, something like (a bit imperative but I accept suggestions):

```
def combine(v1:SparseVector, v2:SparseVector):SparseVector = {
    val size = v1.size + v2.size
    val maxIndex = v1.size
    val indices = v1.indices ++ v2.indices.map(e => e + maxIndex)
    val values = v1.values ++ v2.values
    new SparseVector(size, indices, values)
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I am trying to combine them and represent them in a higher dimensional space like your code snippet.  As a toy example, you could have one feature representing "color" (red, blue) and one feature for "size" (large, small).  Both these features could be mapped to one hot encoding vectors using a Sparse Vector.  But, in order to train in Spark, you need to have all your features in one vector ("featuries") which is why concatenation is necessary I think.

Answer (score 12):

If you have the data in a `DataFrame`, then `VectorAssembler` would be the right thing to use. For example:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

dataset = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(0, Vectors.sparse(10, {0: 0.6931, 5: 0.0, 7: 0.5754, 9: 0.2877}), Vectors.sparse(10, {3: 0.2877, 4: 0.6931, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.6931, 8: 0.6931}))],
["label", "userFeatures1", "userFeatures2"])

assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=["userFeatures1", "userFeatures2"],
    outputCol="features")

output = assembler.transform(dataset)
output.select("features", "label").show(truncate=False)
```

You would get the following output for this:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
|features                                                                   |label|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
|(20,[0,7,9,13,14,16,18],    [0.6931,0.5754,0.2877,0.2877,0.6931,0.6931,0.6931])|0|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 2):

If your vectors represent different columns of a dataframe, you can use [VectorAssembler](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler). Just need to set setInputcols (your 2 vectors) and Spark will make your wish come true ;)